# What is Curb Sliding in Halo Infinite?

Tags: halo-infinite

I keep hearing about a movement technique in Halo Infinite that allows you to move faster called curb sliding.  What is this technique and how do I perform it?

Answer (score 1):

Like you said, curb sliding is the name given to this technique where a player crouches just before hitting the ground after running off a ledge, and then jumping to keep their speed up.

There is a decent (and brief) video here that goes over how to do it:

In short, the steps are:

1. Stand on a small ledge.
2. *Sprint* off of the ledge.
3. Crouch in midair just before hitting the ground.
4. Jump after sliding.

The tricky part is probably step 3, where you need to get the timing correct.  The video also demonstrates that taller ledges are more difficult to perform this on, as you can't simply sprint off and crouch in the air.  For taller ledges, you need to either fall short (meaning stay close to the ledge after running off of it), or run off the ledge at an angle.